# how to set a shared preference

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to set a shared preference but the below code results in `false` on both occasions.

I first get the value of the flag when it doesn't exist and expect a `false`. However, then I set the value to `true` and fetch the flag again and this time I expect `true` but it is still `false`.

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("myapp",0);
    //fetch value when it does not exist
    Boolean mobileFlag = sharedPref.getBoolean("mobile_flag", false);
    Log.d("mobileFlag1", mobileFlag+"");
    //set the value
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("mobile_flag",true);
    //fetch value when it has been set. 
    mobileFlag = sharedPref.getBoolean("mobile_flag", false);
    Log.d("mobileFlag2", mobileFlag+"");
```

both times the results of the log messages is:

```
D/mobileFlag1﹕ false
D/mobileFlag2﹕ false
```

Answer (score 3):

You didn't commit the new value

```
editor.putBoolean("mobile_flag",true).commit();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to commit your changes after you finish editing variables in your SharedPreferences.

```
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

after using `editor.putBoolean("mobile_flag",true);` you need to put `editor.commit()`. This will save your sharedPreference otherwise nothing will be saved.